# Watin+Calendar pick an active date

Tags: javascript, c#, calendar, automated-tests, watin

I have the below code for a read only textfield and a dropdown list:

```
   <div class='formRowNB'>
   <label class="label" for="appointment_date">Date of Appointment
   <abbr title='required'>*</abbr>
   </label><li class="yatri_date input required stringish" id="appointment_date_input">
   <input icon="calendar.gif" id="appointment_date" name="appointments[appointment][date]" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
   <a href="#select">
   <img alt="Calendar" class="calendar_icon" src="/assets/calendar-245ca30eba63389ab5b95465008952fb.gif" /></a>
   </li>
   </div>
   <div class='formRowNB hide' id='non-business-day-message'> You've selected a non-business day.
    </div>
    <div class='formRowNB'>
    <label class="label" for="appointment_time">Time of Appointment
    <abbr title='required'>*</abbr>
    </label><li class="select input required" id="appointment_time_input">
    <select id="appointment_time" name="appointments[appointment][time]"><option value=""></option>    </select>
   </li>
   </div>
```

and this is my watin code to click on calendar and assign a date (based on the defined format)

```
        browser.Image(Find.ByClass("calendar_icon")).Click();
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("appointments[appointment][date]")).Value= "2016-08-01";
```

but the dropdown list is not triggered based on the selected date. Any thought?

Comment: Any idea or even a hint??!!

Comment: it won't because you are setting the field as ....readonly="readonly"...... . If you want to trigger the event chain for that that field needs to be enabled.